# How to add multiple records(rows) in 1 computer ID of DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

[image]

- I want to add multiple rows in 1 computer ID generated, when I press Add, Computer ID will switch to 2, then I want to add another set of multiple records.

Comment: show us the code, and clarify what you are asking with example input and output

Comment: i dont know how to code this..